# How to do await without using callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
let _schedule = await schedule.save(function (err, scheduler) {
      let task = cron.schedule(scheduler.date, async function () {
        let filter = {
          date: scheduler.date,
          _isJobExecuted: false,
          _isDeleted: false
        }
}}
```

In this code how we can use await without using a callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one I haven't tested it but might work.

```
let _schedule = await schedule.save();

let task = cron.schedule(_schedule.date, async function () {
    let filter = {
      date: scheduler.date,
      _isJobExecuted: false,
      _isDeleted: false
    }
});
```